# Exception Inflating nav_graph when passing Parcelable object between Navigation Fragments

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-safe-args

I'm attempting to pass an object between navigation fragments.  I'm able to build the project, but when it launches, I get an error on the nav_graph stating: "Exception inflating nav_graph line 20".  Line 20 is the argument line on the nav_graph.  I just added the @Parcelize keyword to the top of the class I'm trying to pass and setup the nav_graph.  Do I need to do something else?

Team Class:

```
@Parcelize
public class Team {
@SerializedName("idTeam")
@Expose
private String idTeam;
@SerializedName("idSoccerXML")
@Expose
private String idSoccerXML;
@SerializedName("idAPIfootball")
@Expose
private String idAPIfootball;
@SerializedName("intLoved")
@Expose
private String intLoved;
@SerializedName("strTeam")
@Expose
private String strTeam;
@SerializedName("strTeamShort")
@Expose
private String strTeamShort;
```

Nav_Graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.jaykallen.searchapi.ui.HomeFragment"
    android:label="HomeFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_resultsFragment"
        app:destination="@id/resultsFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/resultsFragment"
    android:name="com.jaykallen.searchapi.ui.ResultsFragment"
    android:label="ResultsFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="choice"
        app:argType="com.jaykallen.searchapi.model.Team"
        app:nullable="true" />
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

HomeFragment Method:

```
private fun choiceClicked(chosen: Team) {
    println("User clicked: ${chosen.strTeam}")
    homeViewModel.choice = chosen
    val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToResultsFragment(chosen)
    Navigation.findNavController(view!!).navigate(action)
}
```

ResultsFragment Method:

```
private fun getSafeArgs() {
    arguments?.let {
        val args = ResultsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)
        teamChosen = args.choice
        if (teamChosen != null) {
            println("Safe Argument Received=${teamChosen?.strTeam}")
            updateUi(teamChosen)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, all you needed to do is implement the `Parcelable` interface on your Java object. Normally, if you were using Kotlin, the `@Parcelize` annotation wouldn't have allowed you to compile without the `Parcelable` interface. It seems this compile time protection doesn't work for Java code.

By using Java objects, you'll also lose out on all of the automatic code generation goodies that come with the `@Parcelize` annotation.

In other words, I recommend you convert your Java file to Kotlin if you would like to take advantage of the `@Parcelize` annotation.

Comment: That did it, now my safe args are able to send an object through!  I had to convert my pojo classes to Kotlin and then add Parcelable as an interface.  i.e  @Parcelize
class Team: Parcelable {